# "Solution Not Found" error using Gekko optimization suite when changing parameters, objective function, and initial condition

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to solve multiple optimization problems with various initial conditions using the Gekko suite. Initial conditions are assigned, run optimization using Gekko, and collect each solution. When I try to change parameters, objective function, or initial condition, Gekko often gives me 'Solution Not Found error: line 2130, in solve raise Exception(apm_error).' I am presenting some cases below hoping to get advice to resolve this problem I have. I had a similar question posted earlier, but I hope this question is more concise and clear. Thank you.

Case 1. runs well without error.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = {'A0': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691], 'h': [0.04, 0.25, 0.07, 0, 12.58],'emax': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691] }
dftemp = pd.DataFrame(data=dat)
na=len(dftemp)

# time points
n=51
year=50

# constants
Pa0 = 3.061 
Pe0 = 10.603 
C0 = 100 
r = 0.05 
k=50 
shift=10000000 # to make positive inside log function
ll=0.15

  
for i in range(0,na):
    # create GEKKO model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)

    m.time = np.linspace(0,year,n)
    t=m.time
    
    A0=dftemp.loc[i][0]
    h=dftemp.loc[i][1]
    emax=dftemp.loc[i][2]    
    
    A = m.SV(value=A0, lb=0, ub=A0)
    E = m.SV(value=0, lb=0, ub=A0)

    u = m.MV(value=0, lb=-emax, ub=emax) 
    u.STATUS = 1

    t = m.Param(value=m.time)
    C = m.Var(value=C0)
    d = m.Var(value=1)
    l = m.Param(value=ll)
    
    # Equation
    m.Equation(A.dt()==-u)
    m.Equation(E.dt()==u)
    m.Equation(C.dt()==-C/k)
    m.Equation(d==m.exp(-t*r))
    # Objective (Utility)
    J = m.Var(value=0)
    
    # Final objective
    Jf = m.FV()
    Jf.STATUS = 1
    m.Connection(Jf,J,pos2='end')
    m.Equation(J.dt() == m.log((A+E*(1-l))*h*Pa0-C*u+E*Pe0+shift)*d)
    
    # maximize U
    m.Maximize(Jf)
    
    # options
    m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
    m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
    m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
    
    # solve optimization problem
    m.solve()
    
    # print profit
    print('Optimal Profit: ' + str(Jf.value[0]))
```

Case 2. change number of "time points" from `n=51` to `n=501` Error occurs

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = {'A0': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691], 'h': [0.04, 0.25, 0.07, 0, 12.58],'emax': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691] }
dftemp = pd.DataFrame(data=dat)
na=len(dftemp)

# time points
n=501 
year=50

# constants
Pa0 = 3.061 
Pe0 = 10.603 
C0 = 100 
r = 0.05 
k=50 
shift=10000000 # to make positive inside log function
ll=0.15

   
for i in range(0,na):
    # create GEKKO model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)

    m.time = np.linspace(0,year,n)
    t=m.time
    
    A0=dftemp.loc[i][0]
    h=dftemp.loc[i][1]
    emax=dftemp.loc[i][2]    
    
    A = m.SV(value=A0, lb=0, ub=A0)
    E = m.SV(value=0, lb=0, ub=A0)

    u = m.MV(value=0, lb=-emax, ub=emax) 
    u.STATUS = 1

    t = m.Param(value=m.time)
    C = m.Var(value=C0)
    d = m.Var(value=1)
    l = m.Param(value=ll)
    
    # Equation
    m.Equation(A.dt()==-u)
    m.Equation(E.dt()==u)
    m.Equation(C.dt()==-C/k)
    m.Equation(d==m.exp(-t*r))
    # Objective (Utility)
    J = m.Var(value=0)
    
    # Final objective
    Jf = m.FV()
    Jf.STATUS = 1
    m.Connection(Jf,J,pos2='end')
    m.Equation(J.dt() == m.log((A+E*(1-l))*h*Pa0-C*u+E*Pe0+shift)*d)
    
    # maximize U
    m.Maximize(Jf)
    
    # options
    m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
    m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
    m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
    
    # solve optimization problem
    m.solve()
    
    # print profit
    print('Optimal Profit: ' + str(Jf.value[0]))
```

Case 3. change objective function from `m.log` to simple linear sum. Works well.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = {'A0': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691], 'h': [0.04, 0.25, 0.07, 0, 12.58],'emax': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691] }
dftemp = pd.DataFrame(data=dat)
na=len(dftemp)

# time points
n=51
year=50

# constants
Pa0 = 3.061 
Pe0 = 10.603 
C0 = 100 
r = 0.05 
k=50 
shift=10000000 # to make positive inside log function
ll=0.15
    
for i in range(0,na):
    # create GEKKO model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)

    m.time = np.linspace(0,year,n)
    t=m.time
    
    A0=dftemp.loc[i][0]
    h=dftemp.loc[i][1]
    emax=dftemp.loc[i][2]    
    
    A = m.SV(value=A0, lb=0, ub=A0)
    E = m.SV(value=0, lb=0, ub=A0)

    u = m.MV(value=0, lb=-emax, ub=emax) 
    u.STATUS = 1

    t = m.Param(value=m.time)
    C = m.Var(value=C0)
    d = m.Var(value=1)
    l = m.Param(value=ll)
    
    # Equation
    m.Equation(A.dt()==-u)
    m.Equation(E.dt()==u)
    m.Equation(C.dt()==-C/k)
    m.Equation(d==m.exp(-t*r))
    # Objective (Utility)
    J = m.Var(value=0)
    
    # Final objective
    Jf = m.FV()
    Jf.STATUS = 1
    m.Connection(Jf,J,pos2='end')
    m.Equation(J.dt() == ((A+E*(1-l))*h*Pa0-C*u+E*Pe0+shift)*d)
    
    # maximize U
    m.Maximize(Jf)
    
    # options
    m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
    m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
    m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
    
    # solve optimization problem
    m.solve()
    
    # print profit
    print('Optimal Profit: ' + str(Jf.value[0]))
```

Case 4. change objective function from `m.log` to simple sum, and remove "variable" `d` from the objective function. Error occurs

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = {'A0': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691], 'h': [0.04, 0.25, 0.07, 0, 12.58],'emax': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691] }
dftemp = pd.DataFrame(data=dat)
na=len(dftemp)

# time points
n=51
year=50

# constants
Pa0 = 3.061 
Pe0 = 10.603 
C0 = 100 
r = 0.05 
k=50 
shift=10000000 # to make positive inside log function
ll=0.15

    
for i in range(0,na):
    # create GEKKO model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)

    m.time = np.linspace(0,year,n)
    t=m.time
    
    A0=dftemp.loc[i][0]
    h=dftemp.loc[i][1]
    emax=dftemp.loc[i][2]    
    
    A = m.SV(value=A0, lb=0, ub=A0)
    E = m.SV(value=0, lb=0, ub=A0)

    u = m.MV(value=0, lb=-emax, ub=emax) 
    u.STATUS = 1

    t = m.Param(value=m.time)
    C = m.Var(value=C0)
    d = m.Var(value=1)
    l = m.Param(value=ll)
    
    # Equation
    m.Equation(A.dt()==-u)
    m.Equation(E.dt()==u)
    m.Equation(C.dt()==-C/k)
    m.Equation(d==m.exp(-t*r))
    # Objective (Utility)
    J = m.Var(value=0)
    
    # Final objective
    Jf = m.FV()
    Jf.STATUS = 1
    m.Connection(Jf,J,pos2='end')
    m.Equation(J.dt() == ((A+E*(1-l))*h*Pa0-C*u+E*Pe0+shift))
    
    # maximize U
    m.Maximize(Jf)
    
    # options
    m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
    m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
    m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
    
    # solve optimization problem
    m.solve()
    
    # print profit
    print('Optimal Profit: ' + str(Jf.value[0]))
```

Case 5. change objective function from `m.log` to simple linear sum, and change `shift` to 0. Error occurs

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = {'A0': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691], 'h': [0.04, 0.25, 0.07, 0, 12.58],'emax': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691] }
dftemp = pd.DataFrame(data=dat)
na=len(dftemp)

# time points
n=51
year=50

# constants
Pa0 = 3.061 
Pe0 = 10.603 
C0 = 100 
r = 0.05 
k=50 
shift=0 
ll=0.15
    
for i in range(0,na):
    # create GEKKO model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)

    m.time = np.linspace(0,year,n)
    t=m.time
    
    A0=dftemp.loc[i][0]
    h=dftemp.loc[i][1]
    emax=dftemp.loc[i][2]    
    
    A = m.SV(value=A0, lb=0, ub=A0)
    E = m.SV(value=0, lb=0, ub=A0)

    u = m.MV(value=0, lb=-emax, ub=emax) 
    u.STATUS = 1

    t = m.Param(value=m.time)
    C = m.Var(value=C0)
    d = m.Var(value=1)
    l = m.Param(value=ll)
    
    # Equation
    m.Equation(A.dt()==-u)
    m.Equation(E.dt()==u)
    m.Equation(C.dt()==-C/k)
    m.Equation(d==m.exp(-t*r))
    # Objective (Utility)
    J = m.Var(value=0)
    
    # Final objective
    Jf = m.FV()
    Jf.STATUS = 1
    m.Connection(Jf,J,pos2='end')
    m.Equation(J.dt() == ((A+E*(1-l))*h*Pa0-C*u+E*Pe0+shift)*d)
    
    # maximize U
    m.Maximize(Jf)
    
    # options
    m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
    m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
    m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
    
    # solve optimization problem
    m.solve()
    
    # print profit
    print('Optimal Profit: ' + str(Jf.value[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

For many of these cases, it can help to make a couple changes such as:

- Reformulate to avoid `m.log()` with a negative. The Intermediate variable can also help.

```py
# Objective (Utility)
J = m.Var(value=0)
rhs = m.Intermediate((A+E*(1-l))*h*Pa0-C*u+E*Pe0+shift)
m.Equation(m.exp(J.dt()/d)==rhs)
```

- Initialize before optimizing. The `APOPT` solver does better on the initialization and `IPOPT` does better with the initialized solution from `APOPT`. Initialization strategies are discussed in the [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098135415001179): Safdarnejad, S.M., Hedengren, J.D., Lewis, N.R., Haseltine, E., Initialization Strategies for Optimization of Dynamic Systems, Computers and Chemical Engineering, 2015, Vol. 78, pp. 39-50, DOI: 10.1016/j.compchemeng.2015.04.016.

```py
# solve optimization problem
m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # solver (APOPT)
m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve()

# solve optimization problem
m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
m.options.SOLVER=3 # solver (IPOPT)
m.options.IMODE=6
m.solve()
```

**Case 2: Successful Solutions with n=501**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = {'A0': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691], \
       'h': [0.04, 0.25, 0.07, 0, 12.58],\
       'emax': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691] }
dftemp = pd.DataFrame(data=dat)
na=len(dftemp)

# time points
n=501 
year=50

# constants
Pa0 = 3.061 
Pe0 = 10.603 
C0 = 100 
r = 0.05 
k=50 
shift=10000000 # to make positive inside log function
ll=0.15

for i in range(0,na):
    # create GEKKO model
    m = GEKKO(remote=True)

    m.time = np.linspace(0,year,n)
    t=m.time
    
    A0=dftemp.loc[i][0]
    h=dftemp.loc[i][1]
    emax=dftemp.loc[i][2]    
    
    A = m.SV(value=A0, lb=0, ub=A0)
    E = m.SV(value=0, lb=0, ub=A0)

    u = m.MV(value=0, lb=-emax, ub=emax) 
    u.STATUS = 1

    t = m.Param(value=m.time)
    C = m.Var(value=C0)
    d = m.Var(value=1)
    l = m.Param(value=ll)
    
    # Equation
    m.Equation(A.dt()==-u)
    m.Equation(E.dt()==u)
    m.Equation(C.dt()==-C/k)
    m.Equation(d==m.exp(-t*r))
    # Objective (Utility)
    J = m.Var(value=0)
    rhs = m.Intermediate((A+E*(1-l))*h*Pa0-C*u+E*Pe0+shift)
    m.Equation(m.exp(J.dt()/d)==rhs)
        
    # Final objective
    final = np.zeros_like(m.time)
    final[-1] = 1
    final = m.Param(final)
    
    # maximize U
    m.Maximize(final*J)
        
    # solve optimization problem
    m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
    m.options.SOLVER = 1 # solver (APOPT)
    m.options.IMODE=4
    print('\n\nInitializing with APOPT')
    m.solve(disp=False)

    # solve optimization problem
    m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
    m.options.SOLVER=3 # solver (IPOPT)
    m.options.IMODE=6
    m.solve()
        
    # print profit
    print('Optimal Profit: ' + str(J.value[-1]))
```

Please try this approach with the other cases as well. It is generally better to use `m.sum()` versus `sum` because of the way Gekko constructs the summation as a built-in object versus a long string.

**Edit: Updated Solution** Here is an updated solution with the correct initial conditions. The initial conditions from `IMODE=4` aren't transferring over to `IMODE=6`. An alternative is to use `IMODE=6` with `COLDSTART=1` that is equivalent.

[image: Results]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dat = {'A0': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691], \
       'h': [0.04, 0.25, 0.07, 0, 12.58],\
       'emax': [23221, 2198, 4296, 104906, 691] }
dftemp = pd.DataFrame(data=dat)
na=len(dftemp)

# time points
n=101 
year=50

# constants
Pa0 = 3.061 
Pe0 = 10.603 
C0 = 100 
r = 0.05 
k=50 
shift=10000000 # to make positive inside log function
ll=0.15

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
for i in range(0,na):
    # create GEKKO model
    m = GEKKO(remote=True)

    m.time = np.linspace(0,year,n)
    t=m.time
    
    A0=dftemp.loc[i][0]
    h=dftemp.loc[i][1]
    emax=dftemp.loc[i][2]    

    print('A (initial): ' + str(A0))
    A = m.Var(value=A0, lb=0, ub=A0)
    E = m.Var(value=0, lb=0, ub=A0)

    u = m.MV(value=0, lb=-emax, ub=emax) 
    u.STATUS = 1

    t = m.Param(value=m.time)
    C = m.Var(value=C0)
    d = m.Var(value=1)
    l = m.Param(value=ll)
    
    # Equation
    m.Equation(A.dt()==-u)
    m.Equation(E.dt()==u)
    m.Equation(C.dt()==-C/k)
    m.Equation(d==m.exp(-t*r))
    # Objective (Utility)
    J = m.Var(value=0)
    rhs = m.Intermediate((A+E*(1-l))*h*Pa0-C*u+E*Pe0+shift)
    m.Equation(m.exp(J.dt()/d)==rhs)
        
    # Final objective
    final = np.zeros_like(m.time)
    final[-1] = 1
    final = m.Param(final)
    
    # maximize U
    m.Maximize(final*J)
        
    # solve optimization problem
    m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
    m.options.SOLVER = 1 # solver (APOPT)
    m.options.IMODE=6
    m.options.COLDSTART=1
    print('\n\nInitializing with APOPT')
    m.solve(disp=False)

    # solve optimization problem
    m.options.COLDSTART=0
    m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
    m.options.SOLVER=3 # solver (IPOPT)
    m.options.IMODE=6
    m.solve()
        
    # print profit
    print('Optimal Profit: ' + str(J.value[-1]))

    plt.plot(m.time,A.value,label='A case '+str(i))
    plt.plot(m.time,E.value,label='E case '+str(i))
    plt.plot(m.time,u.value,label='u case '+str(i))
    

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JohnHedengren. I would like to ask about the solution though. I am afraid that the solution from the answer is somehow different from what I have expected. The answer code seems to use fixed initial conditions; 1 for both initial `A` and `E`, which are different from what I want to use (`A0`s from the dat dataframe). Could you advise what I am missing here?

Comment: I fixed the solution. Please see the edit.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHedengren. Problem on `A` and `E` are resolved. I think at this time, somehow an additional restriction seems to be added to `u`. I was expecting a spike of `u` at certain timing for the solution, but instead `u` is evenly distributed across the time with some upper bound that is much lesser than I have set (or at the size to make `A`  zero at the final time).

Comment: May I ask another question? If I replace the upper bound for `u` from `emax` to `A.value`, am I correct to understand that this makes the upper bound at time(t) to `A.value` at the previous time(t-1)? What I want to do is to restrict the bounds for `u` to the maximum value of state variables, which are `A` and `E` at each time.

Comment: You could set up a new inequality constraint such as `m.Equation(u<=A)` and `m.Equation(u<=E)`. If it is the maximum of `A` and `E` for the upper bound then you can use `m.Equation(u<=m.max3(A,E))`. Defining `u.UPPER = max(A.value)` only uses the current value of `A.value` from the initialization and won't give the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JohnHedengren. I think my question was ambiguous. Sorry about that. Just to clarify, if I want to restrict `u` upper bound to the current value of `A` (I believe the current value of `A` changes as the decision point moves on, therefore, `A.value` also evolves accordingly), then can I use `ub=A.value` for `u` upper bound?

Comment: If you have a profile of upper bound values such as [1,5,3,2] that are different at every time point then I recommend creating a new Parameter that can be used to restrict `u` to different values at different time points. It would need to be something like `u_ub=m.Param(A.value)` and `m.Equation(u<=u_ub)`. In this case, `A.value` is from the prior solution and this bound does not change iteration-to-iteration with the solver. Perhaps you could create a very simple example of what you are trying to do as a separate Stack Overflow question?